# get_template_directory() - references parent theme directory

Tags: functions, themes, child-theme

I've got this line in the functions.php of my Child theme:

```
require ( get_template_directory() . '/somecode.php' );
```

However it's giving me the following error:

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required <path/to/parent/theme/somecode.php>
```

where `path/to/parent/theme` is actually the path of the Parent theme rather than the Child theme.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_template_directory()` gives you the path to the parent theme while `get_stylesheet_directory()` gives you the path to the child theme.

**Docs:**

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory